# Not fixed arity for a functor (Prolog)

Tags: prolog

In my Prolog program I have a predicate `reg/1` which says if something is a regular expression.  I'd like to make the program recognize sequences of regular expressions as a regular expression.  So, if `reg(a_1)`, `reg(a_2)`, ..., `reg(a_n)` are all regular expressions, Prolog should answer yes/true to the query `reg(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)`.
But I don't know how to do it.

What I have done is the following:

```
reg([H|T]) :- reg(H), reg(T).
reg([X]) :- reg(X).
```

If, for example, `reg(a)`, `reg(b)`, `reg(c)` are all in the knowledge base, then Prolog answers yes/true to the query `reg([a, b])` or `reg([b, a, c])`, but I can't ask it something like `reg(a, b)` or `reg(b, a, c)`, i.e., I can't get rid of the square brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very uncommon in Prolog to use the same structure with varying arities. To show you one such place where they could have been used but are not, consider directives as they are used to declare a predicate dynamic, multifile, or discontiguous. Say, I want to declare `a/2` and `b/5` dynamic. The following options are possible in ISO-Prolog:

```
:- dynamic(a/2).
:- dynamic(b/5).

:- dynamic([a/2,b/5]). % using a list

:- dynamic((a/2,b/5)). % using an and-sequence
```

Additionally, many Prolog systems have declared `dynamic/1` a prefix operator (as an implementation specific extension) such that you can write:

```
:- dynamic a/2.
:- dynamic b/5.

:- dynamic [a/2,b/5].

:- dynamic a/2, b/5.
```

However, there is no

```
:- dynamic(a/2,b/5).  % does not work
```

which would correspond to your idea.

---

If you really want to use that representation, you will need `(=..)/2` for that. I'd say this is a source of many potential bugs.

---

The only case that comes to mind where a structure with "variable" arity is commonly used are compact representations of sets of variables, as they are used in the implementation of `setof/3`. Instead of using a list of variables `Vs` the structure `V` is used.

```
term_varvect(T, V) :-
    term_variables(T, Vs),
    V =.. ['.'|Vs].         % some use v instead of '.'
```

In systems with a limited `max_arity` you have to handle the overflow case:

```
term_varvect(T, V) :-
    term_variables(T, Vs),
    catch( V =.. ['.'|Vs],
           error(representation_error(max_arity), _),
           Vs = V).
```

Comment: This is a homework, so I can't decide by myself how to represent things.  Actually it is a little bit different from what I said.  My program should recognize as regular expressions everything that is atomic, that is `is_regexp(X) :- atomic(X).`;  and it should answer yes to queries like `is_regexp(seq(a, b, 42, qwe))` for arbitrary sequences.  So I think I have to use something like `(=..)/2`, even if my professors never talked about it.  Or is it in this case different?

Comment: Ops, I was wrong.  They talked about it, and called it univ